# Usuarios con MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy tratando lo siguiente: tengo un `Sitie1.Master` con 3 páginas relacionadas, y una página `Default.aspx` (Que no está relacionada con la MasterPage), el Usuario pone su email en un `TextBox` (Login en `Default.aspx`) quiero que ese valor que lo guardo en un `String` , mostrarlo en un `Label` en las 3 páginas de contenido, por lo pronto tengo eso:

```
    public String Usuario
    {
        get { return (String)ViewState["Usuario"]; }
        set { ViewState["Usuario"] = value; }
    }

        void Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Recibir valor de Default.aspx
        String id = Request.QueryString["Valor"];
        this.Usuario = id;
        LblID.Text = id;
    }
```

No se si este mal, no se como mandar ese valor del `Default.aspx` o si existe otra forma de querer realizar eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uno de los problemas de mandar información en la URL y obtenerlos vía `QueryString` es que **el usuario puede modificar la URL**, así que tienes que tomar precauciones adicionales al tratar esta información. El uso de `ViewState` podría funcionar, pero el problema es que su información "persiste" mientras te mantengas en la página donde almacenaste el contenido. Además, en cada postback que se realiza se envía toda la información que tiene, lo que consume mas ancho de banda. Si luego cambias de página, la información que almacenaste en la página anterior ya no estará disponible.

Una alternativa es el uso de [variables de sesión](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx), puedes crear una en un Default.aspx:

```
Session["correo"] = cajaTextoCorreo.Text;
```

Y luego utilizarla en tus demás páginas, por ejemplo:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       correo= Session["correo"].ToString();
}
```

Como contras, es que consume recursos del lado del servidor, y las variables de sesión están ligadas a la sesión del cliente, pero esta información estará disponible en todas las páginas, hasta que la sesión muera.

Comment: No puedo creer que este tan sencillo! Me funciono perfecto.

Answer (score 2):

Hola podrías almacenarlo como variable de session al usuario actual

```
session["Usuario"] = Request.QueryString["valor"];
```

después en la master page para no estar colocandolo en cada vista definirlo en la cabecera generalmente que se compartira con el restos agregar en `Sitie1.Master`.

`<span ID="lblUsuario" runat="server"></span>`

En el page load de la master pague `Sitie1.Master.cs` agregar:

```
lblUsuario.InnerHtml = session["Usuario"];
```

Con esto deberia funcionar.

Saludos

Comment: También me funciono perfecto, ojala pudiera marcar las dos respuestas.

Comment: Las respuestas son similares, no hace falta mientras se haya solucionado tu duda. Saludos